# how to get pose coordinates from posenet of tensorflow tflite model

Tags: java, android, python, tensorflow

I have used tflite model file of posenet provided by tensorflow.
I am getting output as 4 arrays of 4d which are:

```
[1, 23, 17, 17]
[1, 23, 17, 34]
[1, 23, 17, 64]
[1, 23, 17, 1]
```

My input image size is 353x257.
Now how to get pose coordinated from this output?

Blog I am referring to do this - 
https://medium.com/tensorflow/real-time-human-pose-estimation-in-the-browser-with-tensorflow-js-7dd0bc881cd5

Answer (score 1):

You can reference this new blog that came out which shows how to use PoseNet for Android, it includes a library that does the postprocessing to find key point coordinates, which should be helpful to guide your code logic. 
Basically with the first array had an output of scores, with the dimensions being batch size * height * width * numKeypoints. Each x, y coordinate contains 17 scores, 1 score for each key point. You want to iterate through the height and width and find the x,y coordinate pair with the highest score for each of the 17 key points, this is where that key point lies. Then second array contains offsets, again batch size * height * width * offsets. There are 34 because it is 17 * 2 because each keypoint has an x and y offset. This is needed because the model actually squeezes the image down to 23 * 17 ( in your case) and finds the coordinates for those dimensions, then it needs to expand it back to the original 353 * 257 size using the offsets.

Blog post: https://link.medium.com/AKiU0kq3iZ

And here is the source I’m referring to: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/posenet/android/posenet/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/posenet/lib/Posenet.kt

Hope that helps!

Comment: Any examples for detecting multiple poses? The only examples and demo app only detect single poses.